# C++17 and C++20 library compatibility

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

Lets say I have a C++ library (QT, for example) built with `/std:c++17` and a C++ app built with `/std:c++20` that uses the library.

What will happed if in my app I call a function like [std::string QString::toStdString() const](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qstring.html#toStdString) implemented in the library?

Does `std::string` in my app differ from `std::string` in the library?

Comiler: MSVC2019 or CLang 12.

Comment: No most standard libraries have a stable abi which isn't affected by standard version (with a few exceptions)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is ABI affected by release/debug build configurations?

Comment: yes, in visual studio it is at least

Comment: If they are compiled with different versions of MSVC you are likely to run into problems.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. They compiled with the same MSVC compiler.